# Listing the top value of rows based on a certain value in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-docs

I have the following excel DPS table(s) all listed below eachother:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
Parse     Name      DPS
61        Arlisk    991.7
46        Tritla    913.9

Parse     Name      DPS
79        Arlisk    1156.3
87        Lucija    1090.8
```

I have another name-table, which simply lists the names Arlisk, Tritla and Lucija.
Now I want to add another column to the name-table that shows the highest value found in column D of the other table of all rows that refer to the name of that row.

In other words the new table should list each name's highest DPS found across all the other tables.

I found the following, but the formula is wrong and Im not familiara enough with it to fix it further.

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$999 ,SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$999=$B$4 ,ROW($B$4:$B$999)-ROW($B$4)+1),ROWS($B$4:$B4))),"")))
```

Could anyone give me some advice on the solution?

Comment: Was the solution below able to provide you the answer you were expecting?

Comment: @Nazia: Yes, I completely forgot to resolve it, but just dit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get max DPS per name across all tables?

Given that those tables are in the same columns, then `FILTER` and `MAX` can give you the max DPS per name.

#### Formula:

```
=max(filter(C:C, B:B=E2))
```

#### Output:

[image: OUTPUT]

You could also use the formula below to create a separate table. This will automatically list the unique names together with the max DPS  based on the tables available in the range.

```
=query({B2:C}, "select Col1, max(Col2) where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null group by Col1")
```

#### Output:

[image: output]